# Interrupt executiong of CXF JAX-RS interceptor

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs

Here's JAX-RS CXF (library version is 3.0.1) interceptor:

```
public class CustomInInterceptor extends AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor {

    public CustomInInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE);
    }

    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

If I just throw RuntimeException, I'll receive next output:

`<ns1:XMLFault xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat"><ns1:faultstring xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">java.lang.RuntimeException: 111</ns1:faultstring></ns1:XMLFault>`

My question is, how do I interrupt execution of this interceptor with printing custom (e.g. some neat json) message to a client?

**UPDATE**
I found a way to stop interceptors chain:

```
InterceptorChain chain = message.getInterceptorChain();
chain.abort();
```

But how to set a custom message text?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found is to throw a WebApplicationException:

```
final Response response=Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Some Text").build();
throw new WebApplicationException(response);
```